# What's the default lock granularity in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, locking, granularity, database-locking

I've thoroughly read [MSDN about table hints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx) and I don't seem to find the locking granularity default. Suppose I have the following query:

```
SELECT TOP (1) * FROM MyTable WITH (UPDLOCK, READPAST) ORDER BY SomeColumn ASC;
```

You see, I specified `UPDLOCK` and `READPAST` hints, but not any of granularity hints such as `TABLOCK` or `ROWLOCK`.

Which granularity lock level is used by default?

Comment: By default, it's a row-level lock. When a session/transaction exceeds approx. 5000 row-level locks, the lock is **escalated** to table-level lock (or partition-level, if you have partitioned tables)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no 'default'. The granularity (row, page, (partition | object)) is computed dynamically based on allowed options for the object (allow_page_locks/allow_row_locks), information about the operation intent (probe, scan, insert), the estimated size of the rowset and a number of other factors (isolation level, is filegroup read only etc). In most cases you will get row-level granularity for singleton operations and page-level granularity for scans. The query you posted is probably going to go with page-level granularity because is a scan.